# How to get the time in sync with macOS system clock when using a timer to update the time?

Tags: swift, macos, timer, clock

I'm using this code to show the time in a NSLabel:

**Model**

```
func startClock() {
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    timer?.tolerance = 0.05
    fireAction()
}

@objc dynamic func fireAction() {
    delegate?.timeToUpdateClock(self)
}
```

**ViewController**

```
extension ViewController: ClockWorksProtocol {
    func timeToUpdateClock(_ timer: ClockWorks) {
        tick()
     }
}

 func tick() {
    clockDateLabel.stringValue = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .full, timeStyle: .none)
    clockTimeLabel.stringValue = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .medium)
}
```

Everything seems to work pretty well but unfortunately the seconds shown are not synchronized with the seconds you see in the clock on the menu bar. This happens I think, because I update the clock every second but user don't click when the second is right to start but in a casual interval from a second and the next second (I'm using a timeInterval for the timer of 1.0).

I could change the timeInterval of the timer from 1.0 to 0.1 seconds. This seems to work but I'm afraid this could be too much resource consuming.

I post two screenshots made at the same time. Them show two different time (the seconds):

[image]

[image]

How could I fix the gap?

Comment: Not synchronized in what sense? `Date()` _is_ the time on the clock. It is now, plain and simple.

Comment: I matt, I edited the question to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of a blindly repeating timer, look to see what time it is now and set an interval to fire once at the start of the next second.

Comment: Hi matt, thank you for the useful comment, are you so kind to create an answer so than I can accept it? If you can also add an example to clarify the technique you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two approaches you could take here:

1. Calculate the amount of time `dt` between now and the next exact second.

```swift
let nextSecond = floor(now.timeIntervalSince1970) + 1
let dt = nextSecond - now.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Make a timer that fires once exactly `dt` from now. In the callback for that timer, start a timer that repeats on 1 second intervals (executing `tick()` each time), which is exactly what your `startClock()` function does.

You could also run `tick()` when your first timer fires if you want the ticks to start as soon as possible.

---

2. Determine the moment the next second will occur as a date.

`Date(timeIntervalSince1970: floor(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) + 1)`

Use this init for timer which starts it at a specific `fireAt` date, setting it to repeat every second.

```swift
let timer = Timer(fireAt: 
                      Date(timeIntervalSince1970:
                               floor(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) + 1),
                  interval: 1.0,
                  target: self,
                  selector: #selector(fireAction),
                  userInfo: nil, 
                  repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one of my apps. Unfortunately, information about this issue on the Internet is very rare. For this reason, I hope that my solution can help others.

First, determine the time difference to the next second:

```
let now = Date()
let nextSecond = now.timeIntervalSince1970.rounded(.down) + 1
let intervalToWait = nextSecond - now.timeIntervalSince1970
```

You can now use this calculated time interval to start the timer almost exactly to the next full second. The timer then only needs the interval of one second to work synchronously with the system clock. Why is the initialization code for this missing in my answer? Simple: don't use a standard timer.

The [standard timer class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) is not suitable for this use case. Many corner cases prove this. One of them is when the Mac enters sleep mode. Depending on which millisecond the Mac wakes up, the time is again out of sync with the system clock. Take a look at this fictitious example:

```
tick() => 12:00:00:00
tick() => 12:00:01:00
tick() => 12:00:02:00
tick() => 12:00:03:00
sleep mode => 12:00:03:60
wake up => 12:00:07:30
tick() => 12:00:07:30
tick() => 12:00:08:30
tick() => 12:00:09:30
```

So we need a timer that will not blindly add up one second every time it is activated/reactivated but will do this synchronously with the real time. This can be realized with [DispatchSourceTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcetimer) and [DispatchWallTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchwalltime):

```
private var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!

// ...

self.timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: .strict, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive))
self.timer.schedule(wallDeadline: .now() + intervalToWait, repeating: 1.0, leeway: .nanoseconds(0))
self.timer.setEventHandler(qos: .userInteractive, flags: .enforceQoS) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tick()
    }
}
self.timer.resume()
```

Up to now, none of my users have reported any problems with this solution. Therefore, I assume that the implementation is correct.